# Create a flat plane with beveled edges

Tags: modeling, workflow

[image]

As you may infer from this question, I'm a complete noob. I've gone through quite a few tutorial videos but I still don't understand how I can create this shape...

Comment: Do you mean the beveled edges?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this by modifying a simple plane.

1. Add a plane: <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd> -> Mesh -> Plane
2. Go into edit mode: <kbd>Tab</kbd>
3. Go into vertices mode: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Tab</kbd> -> <kbd>1</kbd>
4. Select all vertices: <kbd>A</kbd>
5. Bevel vertices: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>B</kbd>

[image]

---

This will create an ngon, ideally we would only like quads (faces with only four vertices)

If you want to fix this you can easily connect two vertices.

1. Select two opposing vertices and connect them by <kbd>J</kbd>
2. Repeat until all ngons are gone

[image]